# p:dataList rendering in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: jsf, primefaces, internet-explorer-8

my page contains a data list within another data list. The outer data list simulates an accordion panel, while the inner data list renders my dynamic columns.

Everything works fine, but Internet Explorer 8 behaves differently in respect of Firefox and Chrome, because in the resulting html it renders some empty objects that leaves a blank space before data.

The screenshots show the differences between Explorer 8 and Firefox.

Firefox generated HTML:
[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7865852/col_din_firefox.png]

Explorer 8 generated HTML:
[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7865852/col_din_ie8.png]

Firefox rendering:
[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7865852/col_din_rendered_firefox.png]

Explorer 8 rendering:
[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7865852/col_din_rendered_ie8.png]

Here is the code:

```
<p:dataList id="data" styleClass="myDataList" value="#{bean.getAnag(idSito)}" var="tipologia" itemType="disc" type="definition">
  <div class="ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset ui-hidden-container tabAccordion" style="width: 100%;">
    <table id="accordionFake#{idSito}" border="1" class="table-din-col" style="display: none; margin-bottom: 10px;">
      <!-- HEADERS -->
      <tr class="table-din-col-titolo">
        <td style="padding: 4px;">
          <h:outputText value="Codice" />
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 4px;">
          <h:outputText value="Descrizione" />
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 4px;">
          <h:outputText value="CodiceAgg" />
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 4px;">
          <h:outputText value="Pos" />
        </td>
        <p:dataList value="#{bean.buildColumns(idSito)}" var="colDin" type="definition">
          <td>
            <h:outputText value="#{colDin.header}" />
          </td>
        </p:dataList>
      </tr>
      <!-- HEADERS -->

      <!-- ROWS BUILDING -->                        
      <p:dataList id="dataL" var="rilevazione" selectionMode="single"
                value="#{bean.getLsLoc(idSito)}" type="definition">
        <tr class="table-din-col-righe">
          <td class="table-din-col-colonne">
            <h:outputText id="codice" value="#{rilevazione.codice}" />
          </td>
          <td class="table-din-col-colonne">
            <h:outputText id="desc" value="#{rilevazione.descrizione}" />
          </td>
          <td class="table-din-col-colonne">
            <h:outputText id="codSnam" value="#{rilevazione.codiceAgg}" />
          </td>
          <td class="table-din-col-colonne">
            <h:outputText id="pos" value="#{rilevazione.pos}" />
          </td>

          <p:dataList value="#{bean.buildColumns(idSito)}" var="colDin" type="definition">
            <td class="table-din-col-colonne">
              <h:outputText value="#{colDin.property.valore}" />
            </td>
          </p:dataList>
        </tr>
      </p:dataList>
      <!-- ROWS BUILDING -->
    </table>
  </div
</p:dataList>
```

How can I instruct ie8 to correctly render the data lists?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It look like you was using the wrong component for the purpose, or are at least not understanding/familiar with basic HTML.

The `<p:dataList>` gives you the option to generate a HTML `<ul><li>` (unordered list), `<ol><li>` (ordered list) or `<dl><dt><dd>` (definition list).

However, you seem to be after generating a plain vanilla HTML `<table><tr><td>` with all cells hardcoded. You have nested a `<p:dataList type="definition">` inside `<tr>` which would only generate `<dl><dt><dd>` elements inplace where `<td>` elements are expected. This only ends up in [illegal HTML syntax](http://validator.w3.org/). IE is rather sensitive to that.

You should replace the nested `<p:dataList type="definition">` components by `<ui:repeat>`. It doesn't generate any HTML and your HTML will end up syntactically valid (although I wonder how it makes sense to have a `<dl><dt><dd><table>`, after all, I suggest to learn [basic HTML](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/html/beginner/) as well, so that you can better understand which JSF components to pick for the purpose).

Comment: I ended up using these components because I need to generate tables with dynamic columns, and those tables are within an accordion panel, with every tab containing one table (you can wonder why I'm using tables inside an accordion panel, but this is not under my control).
I tried to use p:columns, but it does not work for me, because it gets the wrong columns (to be more specific, it always gets columns from the first data table).
I will try ui:repeat, thanks.